# Word or phrase to mean 'perfectly accurate?'

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word or phrase in English that means accurate to an infinite level of precision? For example, the measurement of a length that is 'perfectly accurate' records the length down to its final decimal place.

Comment: Just for benefit of people seeking by title - the phrase describing perfectly accurate to be used in common-day English, as opposed to (requested) "scientific accuracy" is **Spot-on**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a mathematical context, the word would be ***exact***. An exact calculation always gives the mathematically expected result. The opposite is ***approximate***: an approximate calculation gives a result that is close to the exact result, but not identical. For example, the circumference of a circle of radius 1 is *exactly* 2π, which is *approximately* 6.283. These words are also used in computer contexts: for example, financial calculations are usually done with *exact arithmetic* (using integers or fixed-point decimal numbers, with well-defined rounding rules), whereas physical calculations are usually done with *inexact* or *approximate* arithmetic (using floating-point numbers, with rounding rules that are intended to maximize the precision of the result but not always to be perfectly reproducible).

Strictly speaking, a physical measurement cannot be exact (the length of a stick has no “final decimal place”). However you can still use the word *exact* to mean that the precision of the measurement is so great that the uncertainty about the measured quantity will never matter. You can also use *perfectly accurate* in this context (again, meaning so accurate that any inaccuracy is irrelevant).

Comment: "Precise" can be another option.

Comment: @Mistu4u No, *precise* is a relative term, not an absolute term. A measurement to 1% accuracy is *more precise* than a measurement to 10% accuracy. A measurement that is said to be *precise* may not be perfectly accurate, no more than a *tall* person is infinitely high.

Comment: @Gilles, that's only because of the dilution of the language. Apparently "precise" has lost its precision. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/precise  _2.  Exact, as in performance, execution, or amount; accurate or correct: a precise measurement; a precise instrument._

Comment: @TecBrat True, there are contexts where the two words can be used interchangeably, but not all of them. A *precise* clock might stay accurate for months; a *very precise* clock might stay accurate for a lifetime. (Notice the qualifier *very*? You can't use it with *exact*, except for stylistic effect.) An *exact* clock would always tell the time. As far as I know, *precise* was never specifically about exactness, so it isn't a matter of dilution of language — rather a general manifestation of imprecision (but not inexactness), where a relative term gets a sideline as an absolute.

Comment: @Giles: I disagree - and so does OED, which defines ***precisely:** With precise or **exact** correspondence, in every detail; with **complete accuracy***. I think you're overly influenced by mathematical contexts where "precision" is a "variable" attribute relating to ***how*** accurate a value is.